# Dictionary in WatchOs is always empty when calling updateApplicationContext

Tags: swift, dictionary, watchos-2

i have a Problem with WatchOs 2.1 with Swift.
I want to send some Data in a Dictionary to my iPhone.
But if i create my Dictionary with the Information to send to my iPhone, this Dictionary is empty, if i debug it. But if i print my dictionary, the values are shown on command line. If i Use NSMutableDictionary my Dictionary is filled with my Values while debugging, but i cannot send a NSMutableDictionary with the  updateApplicationContext Function. Anyone has an idea, how to solve this Problem

```
 //try to get new Data
        let dict : [String: AnyObject] = [
            "action" : 9
        ]
        do {
            try session.updateApplicationContext(dict
            )
            print("start session with watch")
        } catch let error as NSError {
            NSLog("Updating the context failed: " + error.localizedDescription)
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is an answer, but I'd say don't trust the debugger here. In my experience the debugger often has trouble displaying data dealing with AnyObject objects. You could just try adding the expression "Array(dict.keys)" to the debugger to at least prove what keys exist in the Dictionary. Other than that, I say just trust that it works. :-)

Comment: Thanks for your help, but the Problem is, that the the session-Function in my Appdelegate Class does not get called

Comment: Doesn't get called? Or fails? If you put a breakpoint on the "let dict" line, where does it go when you step?

Comment: Oh wait i just realized you mean the session(session: WCSession, didReceiveApplicationContext applicationContext: [String : AnyObject]) on the iPhone side. Did you make sure to make your AppDelegate object the delegate for the session, and Activate the session? Are other WCSession communications going through?

Comment: I fixed it, yes i meant the session you mentioned. 
But i don't know how i fixed it. Maybe the session was not activated. Thanks for your help!